# What essential property justifies the name "derivative"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, sheaf-theory, differential-operators

Most, if not all, of the notions of derivative that I have so far seen have the property that they are locally defined -- meaning that the derivative of a map-type object at a point depends on the map only in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of said point.

One could define some sort of non-local "differential" operator in real analysis for example by convolving a derivative with a function having non-trivial support.  I use quotes here, because the operator involves integration as well as differentiation.

A less explicit but more apropos example would be an operator $N$ taking a manifold morphism $\phi$ to a vector bundle morphism $N\phi$, but which does not respect the restriction and gluing concepts used in sheaf theory (which I understand to be an abstract way to say that something is locally defined).  The tangent map operator on manifold morphisms is a similar type of object, except that it can be shown to be locally defined.  Thus $N\phi$ would "taste" like a derivative in that it has the same form as $T\phi$, but is not locally defined.

1. Could an operator such as $N$ qualify as a differential operator (equivalently, would $N\phi$ qualify as a derivative of $\phi$)?
2. Generally, what is the essential quality defining a "derivative"?  My guess is that an answer would live in the realm of sheaf theory.

Comment: A keyword you might search for is *pseudo-differential operators*, which is usually attached to well-behaved operators in that spirit...

Comment: Yes, pseudo-differential operators are defined by convolution and are somehow not local but very close to being local.

Comment: As for «what's the essential quality of a differential operator», one answer is Peetre's theorem. (Wikipedia's write-up on this is particularly obfuscated, so Googling a bit might be helpful)

Comment: A notion of derivative applies for functions on many finite sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say). Though the Banach algebra of bounded functions on a finite set turns out to carry no nonzero derivations, one can pick a suitable function space for which the interpolation problem has a unique solution and differentiate the interpolant. This is intrinsically non-local.


Comment: Re: my comment above, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32667/numerical-mathemtics-how-to-solve-hexagonal-central-differences/32672#32672

Comment: Thank you Mariano, that's a really neat and apropos result.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman, does 'finite' [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86996/what-essential-property-justifies-the-name-derivative#comment223844_86996) mean something other than the usual set-theoretic notion?  Otherwise it's hard to know what else a (real- or complex-valued) function on a finite set could be *than* bounded.

Comment: @LSpice 'finite' is taken in the usual sense. IIRC I was trying to emphasize the Banach algebra structure, which more generally requires boundedness as an explicit condition

Comment: @SteveHuntsman, OK, I see.